# AdaptiveCards in Skype (UWP)

Tags: bots, botframework, adaptive-cards

I am playing with adaptive cards, using sample JSON from http://adaptivecards.io/samples (restaurant sample).  The card renders fine within the emulator. It is shrunk in Facebook (known to be not supported at this point), but in Skype, no card displayed, and when I check the bot dashboard, I have a warning for "Unknown attachment type"

I was under the impression that adaptive cards were supported on Skype, or is this because it is UWP Skype application?

Comment: Skype is planning on shipping support over the next couple of months.

Answer (score 1):

I think adaptive cards are not supported yet on skype, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/get-started/bots#channel-status)